# Condition within for loop not executing

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a trivial program that doubles the amount of rice grains per each square on a chess board. I'm trying to work out the amount of squares required for at least 1 000 000 000 grains of rice. The problem is, what ever I try, the second if statement gets skipped even though 'test' is false after first iteration.

I've tried an else after the if statement, but the else is skipped when 'test' variable is false.

```
    constexpr int max_rice_amount = 1000000000;  
    int num_of_squares = 0;
    int rice_grains = 0;
    bool test = true; // so we can set rice_grains amount to 1

    for (int i = 0; i <= max_rice_amount; i++)
    {
        if (test == true)
        {
            rice_grains = 1;  // This will only happen once
            test = false;
        }
        else if (test == false)
            rice_grains *= 2;

        ++num_of_squares;
        std::cout << "Square " << num_of_squares << " has " << rice_grains << " grains of rice\n";

    }
```

Comment: What do you expect that `rice_grains * 2;` does?

Comment: `rice_grains * 2;` - I suspect you meant `rice_grains *= 2;`.

Comment: Your termination condition doesn't match your explanation

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but since `num_of_squares` is always equal to `i` at the end of the loop body, there's no need for two separate variables. Just use `num_of_squares` for the loop control: `int num_of_squares = 0; for ( ; num_of_squares <= max_rice_amount; ++num_of_squares)`.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the first few iteration with a debugger?

Comment: @JVApen Apologies, I have made an edit. But now 'rice_grains' remains 0? It doesn't multiply by 2 for each square. The idea is that I need 'rice_grains' to multiply by 2 for each square, but obviously not for the first square as I only want 1 grain for that square. Hope that's clear?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah. It just totally skips the second if statement. But why does it do this if 'test' is set to false after first iteration?

Comment: And in the debugger you see that the variable `test` is indeed equal to `false`? And the code you show us, is it copy-pasted from your actual code? If not, do you have `test = false` in the condition instead?

Comment: Ok. Just realised it was the fact rice_grains * 2 was a blank expression. But the debugger didn't even show it was going to the second if statement.

Comment: That's probably because the compiler was smart enough to see that the statement didn't do anything, and it optimized it away. You can easily veryfy that be looking at the generated code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude seems to be working fine now. A school boy error on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` causes the issue. But C++ is more powerful than you can imagine. Rework your loop to

```
for (
    int rice_grains = 1, num_of_squares = 1;
    rice_grains <= max_rice_amount;
    rice_grains *= 2, ++num_of_squares
){
```

with

```
 std::cout << "Square " << num_of_squares << " has " << rice_grains << " grains of rice\n";
```

as the loop body; and weap at the beauty.

Comment: Never seen a for loop written this way!

Comment: Well you have now!

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit - that surprises me - I find it to be very readable. The OP is essentially maintaining a linear and an exponential counter and I preserve that symmetry in this approach. Perhaps I’m more warped than I think.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem description, this looks a good fit for a `while` loop or a `do-while` loop.

```
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    constexpr int max_rice_amount = 1000000000;  

    int num_of_squares = 1;
    int rice_grains = 1;

    while (rice_grains < max_rice_amount)
    {
        std::cout << "Square " << num_of_squares << " has " << rice_grains << " grains of rice\n";
        rice_grains *= 2;
        ++num_of_squares;
    }
}
```

[Code at compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1KTLWA)

Here you recognize 3 big blocks:

- Initialization
- The 'until' condition in the while
- The manipulation